# Bson interface has some problems

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I uesd MongoDB v3.6.4 with mgo(gopkg.in/mgo.v2) package

Bson

```
var id interface{}  
id = 249678041972736  
bson.M{"_id": id}  
var id int64  
id = 249678041972736  
bson.M{"_id": id}
```

Tow bsons are not same?
eg:

```
func GetUser(id interface{}) (*User, error) {  
    session := MongoDB()  
    defer session.Close()  
    var m *User  
    err := session.DB.C("user").Find(&bson.M{"_id": id}).One(&m)  
    // ！！！err: not found  
    if err != nil {  
        return nil, err  
    } else {  
        return m, nil  
    }
}
```

but:

```
func GetUser(id int64) (*User, error) {  
    session := MongoDB()  
    defer session.Close()  
    var m *User  
    err := session.DB.C("user").Find(&bson.M{"_id": id}).One(&m)  
    // !!! err == nil 
    if err != nil {  
        return nil, err  
    } else {  
        return m, nil  
    }
}  

GetUser(id interface{}) can get err (not found)  
GetUser(id int64) can get nil err
```

Pay attention to error

I used function GetUser and import same value 249678041972736 
but different parameter type get different result

Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It works for me. What MongoDB version are you using? And which `mgo` package?

Comment: using v3.6.4 with mgo.v2

Comment: Which `mgo`? Use https://github.com/globalsign/mgo.

Comment: gopkg.in/mgo.v2

Comment: That `mgo` package is unmaintained. Please try with the one I posted.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help

Comment: I think if you are using interface you have to type assert its underlying to fetch exact value.

Comment: mgo should do it

Comment: oh no~, my db value "_id" type int64,when i use string to find it, can not found any result! this is MongoDB 
requirements？

Answer (score 0):

You are putting an unnecessary & in front of the bson.M{…

```
err := session.DB.C("user").Find(bson.M{"_id": id}).One(&m)
```

The use of bson.M in the find is also unnecessary, mgo has a call of FindId specifically for the search you are doing.

```
err := session.DB.C("user").FindId(id).One(&m)
```

gopkg.in/mgo.v2 is now marked as unmaintained. github.com/globalsign/mgo and github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson are the two maintained forked libraries. I have found no problems using them instead pf gopkg.in

Comment: if type id is string, i get 'not found'

Comment: I use strings as ids all the time and if you are getting not found error then the string isn't being used as an id. Confirm with an app like MongoDB Compass or MongoHub etc. If you want to use the Mongo javascript engine try: use <collection> then: db.user.find({"_id": "<string>"})